# PHP EscPOS - save raw data & execute later

Tags: php, escpos

I'm able to execute the commands directly to the printer using the `WindowsPrintConnector` but I need to save the raw data of EscPOS so I can use / execute it later.

This works great:

```
$connector = new WindowsPrintConnector('Generic');
$printer = new Printer($connector);
$printer->text("Hello world\n");
$printer->close();
```

But I want to save the raw data and execute it later.

I started by using the `DummyPrintConnector` class and save the raw data into a txt file.

```
$connector = new DummyPrintConnector();
$printer = new Printer($connector);
$printer->text("Hello world!\n");
$printer->cut();

$data = $connector->getData();

file_put_contents('example.txt', $data);

$printer->close();
```

This saves in the txt file the following data:

[image]

Then I tried to read the txt file and execute it using the `WindowsPrintConnector`:

```
$data = file_get_contents('example.txt');

$connector = new WindowsPrintConnector('Generic');
$printer = new Printer($connector);
$printer->text($data);
$printer->close();
```

But the paper output is `?VA??@Hello world!` instead of `Hello world!`.

**Questions**:

1. Can I save the raw data in a txt file?
2. How do I make the printer to execute the commands properly?

---

**Edit 1)**

Trying to print directly the data obtained also doesn't work. For example:

```
$connector = new DummyPrintConnector();
$printer = new Printer($connector);
$printer->text("Hello world!\n");
$data = $connector->getData();
$printer->close();

$connector = new WindowsPrintConnector('Generic');
$printer = new Printer($connector);
$printer->text($data); // Wrong chars
$printer->textRaw($data); // Wrong chars
$printer->close();
```

Comment: Without any knowledge of this system, my assumption would be that printers would have a meta-language, and I wouldn’t be surprised if they used the first 32 bytes for this. In your first code block, you add “text”, but then call “getData”. You then pass that data back to the “text” method. Does the printer have a “raw data” property/method/something that you can set? Otherwise, why do you need to serialize the “printer” in the first place, can’t you just serialize the data in your own logic, and apply it to the final printer only?

Comment: @ChrisHaas I need to save / serialize the data because I'll be sending this through API. Instead of sending a PDF, I'll be sending this raw data through a txt file (or anything better) so the API users can extract and execute it directly in their printers.

Comment: I’m seeing some methods about raw text and/or a manual buffer, that might be something to look into? I just don’t think that you’ll be able to round-trip from “text” to “data” (which I’d assume includes printer commands), back to text. Maybe text to data to raw text though?

Comment: @ChrisHaas I've tried the `->textRaw($data)` without success. I wasn't aware of the manual buffer, I believe you're talking about the class `EscposPrintBuffer`, which I just tested using `writeTextRaw` and got the same output. I'm currently using a Generic Text/Only driver because I couldn't find the drivers for the current POS Printer I have, dunno if it's a problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**.

The data returned from `->getData()` is OK, but we cannot use `->text()` nor `->textRaw()` functions to print the contents of saved data.

Instead we should copy the contents directly to the printer, like such:

```
copy($file, "//shared-pc/shared-printer");
```

Also, instead of using the `DummyPrintConnector` class we can use the `FilePrintConnector` which is a better approach for those, like me, who need to save the file.

**Solution 1)**

```
$filename = 'example.txt'; // You can save as 'example.bin' if you wish
$connector = new FilePrintConnector($filename);
$printer = new Printer($connector);
$printer->text("Hello world!\n");
$printer->cut();
$printer->close();

// Send bin data directly to the printer
copy($filename, "//your-pc//your-shared-printer");
```

**Solution 2)**

```
$filename = 'example.txt';
$connector = new DummyPrintConnector();
$printer = new Printer($connector);
$printer->text("Hello world!\n");
$printer->cut();

file_put_contents($filename, $connector->getData());

$printer->close();

// Send bin data directly to the printer
copy($filename, "//your-pc//your-shared-printer");
```